# Track field changes in code

Tags: apex, developer-console

A field on a custom object is getting its value from somewhere, and we are not sure where! Is it possible to track code-level changes on a custom field, maybe in the Developer Console?

UPDATE: A field can be updated in multiple places before landing a final value. I want to see all code changes (NOT db changes) in a table like this (this is a hypothetical example):

1. 07:15:29:56 ContactTrigger set Contact.Email = 'test1@bs.com'
2. 07:15:29:61 Package Code set Contact.Email = 'test2@bs.com'
3. 07:15:29:84 Contact Workflow set Contact.Email = null
4. 07:15:29:89 ContactTrigger set Contact.Email = 'test3@bs.com'

So even though I expect to see 'test2@bs.com' for the Email field, I get 'test3@bs.com'.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to track specifically a single field value, however, you could attempt to write a trigger on the object which could try to grab its log file and dump it to an email or another custom object, use field tracking to try to hunt down the update, or, set up logs to be saved when the object gets updated in salesforce. The last ones a little weird, you can only set a max of 5 or so logs, but its possible. What Id do is  open the dev console, and update the record in such a way that it would trigger your update, and check those logs.

Comment: But I haven't seen anywhere in the logs that show value changes for a field. I emphasize on "code changes" as opposed to "db changes"! Think of the field as a variable whose value gets set and unset here and there (not best practice, but it does happen if you work with off-site unexperienced SF developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the APEX & SYSTEM logs to FINEST I was able to get the value assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible
You can search field API name in all files using developer console.
Open Developer console -> edit -> search in files.

Comment: I am looking for changes to the field value, not references to the field name. Please see updated question.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an update trigger on this field. Once this field's value changes,  it's logged in a document in system.

Comment: I want to see ALL changes that are made to the field by code. See updated question. Thanks.